# Sqlite. How to create an index in attached DB?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a problem with adding index to memory database attached to main database.

1) I open the database (F) from file

2) Attach the :memory: (M) database

3) Create tables in database M

4) Copy data from F to M

I would also like to create an index in database M, but don't know how to do that.
This code creates index but in F database:

```
sQuery = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS [INDID] ON [PANEL]([ID]  ASC);";
```

I tried to add the name qualifier before table name like this:

```
sQuery = "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS [INDID] ON [M.PANEL]([ID]  ASC);";
```

but SQLite returns with message that column main.M.PANEL does not exist.

What can I do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<strike>just put the square brackets around the prefix [M].[panel] or just skip them</strike>

UPD: you shoud set prefix [before](http://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) the **index** name instead of the table name:

```
sqlite> attach database ":memory:" as m;
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------
0    main
2    m
sqlite> create table m.users (id int, name TEXT);
sqlite> create unique index m.qwe on users (name);
sqlite> insert into m.users VALUES(2,'asd');
sqlite> insert into m.users VALUES(3,'asd');
Error: column name is not unique
```

Comment: Both (M.PANEL and [M].[PANEL]) generate error message: `SQLITE_ERROR[1]: near ".": syntax error`.

Comment: Now works fine! Thanks!
What we have to remember is that DB name and index name can't be both in one brackets: `[M.INDID] //Wrong!`.

Comment: I want to create a index from the application and not a static data. Is it possible to specify index in the row insert time?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `idxuserID` ON `userFlag` (
    `userID`
);
```